# R count frequency efficiently

Tags: r

Let's say I have a problem in which I have a vector, called, bases defined as

```
bases <- c(1:100000)
```

And I create a random other vector called instances, defined randomly as

```
instances <- c(12, 367, 442, 551, 1882, 2556, 13222, 13772, 18999, 26000, 29004, 83027)
```

How can I count how many of the instance elements fall within each 1:1000 window of the bases vector?

For example, to clarify what I mean, the 1:1000 window should be given a frequency of 4, for the instances' elements (12, 367, 442, and 551). The window 84001:85000 should have a frequency of zero.

I plan to have a much larger bases vector (but continuous from 1:n) and also a much larger instances vector in which all instance values are less than n. Also please keep the window size modifiable.

Can anyone provide an efficient solution?

Thanks. Please excuse my ignorance as I am new to R and still learning R programming as a high school student.

Comment: Look at `findInterval` and `cut`.

Comment: ...and probably `table` or `tabulate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you are looking for an histogram. Use the `hist` function.

```
bases <- c(1:100000)
instances <- c(12, 367, 442, 551, 1882, 2556, 13222, 13772, 
               18999, 26000, 29004, 83027)

# plot = 0 prevents plotting 
# breaks are the values at which we want to split our interval 
h <- hist(instances, breaks = seq(0, max(bases), 1000), plot=0)
```

Now `h$counts` will contain the counts in each bin.

Comment: I think this is the most efficient and sensible way to do this, since I was planning on plotting a histogram anyways later on :)